# How to login not with a username but a different selector?

Tags: authentication, meteor

I want to implement "Login with username or customerID (never both) and password" where I let the user enter a username or their customerID in the first field and password in the second field.

The `accounts-password` package lets me login using a username by calling

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(<username>,<password>);

                       OR

var selector = {username: <username>}
Meteor.loginWithPassword(selector, <password>);
```

I tried to select the user using the selector.

```
var selector = {customerID: <customerID>}
```

But it seems that I can use only `_id`,`username` or `email` in this way to select a user or I get a `Match failed` error.

Isn't there any other method to log a user in without a `username`, `_id` or `email`?

Comment: At the moment those are the only fields that are allowed. You could try and wrap the `login` method on the server, or register your own login handler. This is not entirely trivial as the handler registration is not well documented.

Comment: @MasterAM, is it possible that retrieving _id from customerID and then logging in using _id will pose a security problem?

Comment: It would likely not be a security threat on its own, but I don't regard myself a security expert. It is a bit of information that you may not be interested to expose this way. It is likely that the user ids are stored in other collections and visible to the client anyway, but you should be considerate as to how users can retrieve them. Generally, knowing a user`s (or, for this matter, any object's) id, should not grant any privilege to the one holding the knowledge. It should not be used as a shared secret.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround is the farthest I have reached:

### 1. First retrieve the `username` or `_id` using `customerID`.

### 2. Then login using the retrieved `username`/`_id` and password.

```
//SERVER
Meteor.methods({
    findIDFromCustomerID: function(customerID){
        user = Meteor.users.findOne({customerID: customerID});
        if(user){
            return user._id;
        }else{
            throw new Meteor.Error(403,"User not found");
        }
    }
});

//CLIENT
Meteor.call('findIDFromCustomerID',<customerID>,function(err,data){
    if(data && !err){
        Meteor.loginWithPassword({id: data}, <password>);
    }
});
```

But in this, I feel that I leave a small window for the misbehaving users.